# If $\mathcal N$ non measurable, $\{0\}\times \mathcal N$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^2$, but $m(\{0\}\times \mathcal N)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We define product measure on complete measurable spaces because if $N$ is a nul set and $M$ is measurable, we want that $$m_2(N\times M)=m_1(N)m_1(M)=0.$$
Let $(\mathbb R^2, \mathcal M\times \mathcal M, m_2)$ the Lebesgue measure space on $\mathbb R^2$. We have that $$\mathcal M\times \mathcal M=\sigma (\{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\}),$$
and it's a complete measurable space. I know that for all $A\times B\in \mathcal M\times \mathcal M$ we have that $$m_2(A\times B)=m_1(A)m_1(B).\tag{*}$$

But if $\mathcal N$ is non measurable (for example Vitali set), then $\{0\}\times \mathcal N$ has measure $0$ and thus is in $\mathcal M\times \mathcal M$. But don't we have that $$m_2(\{0\}\times \mathcal N)\neq m_1(\{0\})m_1(\mathcal N) \ \ ?$$
So $(*)$ is wrong ? Could someone explain ?

Comment: The detail here is that the Vitali set $\mathcal{N}$ is not in the sigma algebra $\mathcal{M}$ that you are considering for which $(\star)$ holds, precisely because it is not measurable.

Comment: $\mathcal{N}\notin\mathcal{M}$

Comment: The expression $m(A \times B) = mA \cdot mB$ is only valid if both $A,B$ are measurable. However, in a complete measure space **any** subset of a set of measure zero has measure zero.

Comment: @copper.hat: So you agree that $\{0\}\times \mathcal N\in \mathcal M\times \mathcal M$ (since it has measure $0$ it is measurable, no ?)

Comment: No. If the $\sigma$-field containing $\mathcal M\times \mathcal M$ is complete then $\{0\} \times \mathcal N$ will be in the $\sigma$-field.

Comment: So in fact $\mathcal M\times \mathcal M=\{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\}$, i.e. $\{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\}=\sigma \{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\}$ ? If no, which element is in $\mathcal M\times \mathcal M$ but not in $\{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\}$ ? I'm a bit confuse with all this... because for me $\mathcal M\times \mathcal M$ was complete... but it looks that it's not. If $\{A\times B\mid A,B\in\mathcal M\}\neq \sigma \{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\}$, how can you show that $\{0\}\times \mathcal N$ not in $\sigma \{A\times B\mid A,B\in \mathcal M\}$ ?@copper.hat